# HTML tags stripped out in POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, ckeditor

I am working on preview feature of editting page in ckeditor.
After any changes in field I am POSTing body to preview action and then saving it to session.
After that I fetch data using GET.
Unfortunatelly the body I have post is returned without any html tags so I can't preview images:[

Here's an previewAction:

```
public function previewAction() {
  if($_POST) {
    $id = rand(1, 100000);
    unset($_SESSION['preview']);
    if(isset($_POST['body'])) {
        $_SESSION['preview'][$id] = array( 'body'=> $_POST['body'] );
        echo $id;
        exit;
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception('Body not posted for preview');
    }
  }
  elseif($this->params['param1']) {
    $id = $this->params['param1'];
    $page = new page();
    $page->populate($_SESSION['preview'][$id]);
    $this->view->page = $page;
    $this->contentRender = 'index/page.php';
    $this->render = 'content_only.php';
  }
  else {
    exit;
  }
```

And js function handling preview:

```
function updateSubmit(force) {
  if(timeout_id)
    clearTimeout(timeout_id);
  if(cke && ( (busy==false && update_needed == true) || force==true ) ) {
    timeout_id = setTimeout(function() {
    if(busy==false) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/index/preview/',
          data: {body: cke.getData()},
          success: function(data) {
            $.each(iframe, function() {
                $(this).attr('src', '/index/preview/'+data);
            });
            busy = false;
            update_needed = false;
          }
        }
        )
    }
    }
    , 200);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Why would you fetch the data using GET?

Comment: Please show some example code that you are getting

Comment: Use Firebug to see what your AJAX call is sending out. There's nothing in PHP that would auto-strip tags unless you explicitly put it there, so make sure the AJAX is sending out the proper HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `cke.getData()` function dont strip out the tags.

Or in PHP somewhere before this script you don't have strip_tags() or sth.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you are doing it wrong. Do not fetch the data using GET, just create hidden field if you need. 
I don't think you need a SESSION here.

Answer (score 0):

cke.getData() does not strip tags out.
Session is not necesery in this script, however it's not an issue. Html is without tags after readig from $_POST['body'].